# How to retrieve the only item in a set containing one item

Tags: julia

I have a set containing a single item, in this case a string:

```
b = Set(["A"])
```

I want to get that single item out. What's the best way of doing this? The only way I can figure out to do it is using a loop:

```
single_item = ""
for item in b
    single_item = item
end
```

which gets my what I need

```
julia> single_item
"A"
```

but I feel like there must be an easier way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest `first`

```
julia> b = Set(["A"])
Set(ASCIIString["A"])

julia> first(b)
"A"
```

We can profile this, looking at number of allocations. (since memory allocating is slow). I would ignore the actual timing since this is a single run.
The results shown are the second run of each call. with `b` declared `const`.

```
julia> @time first(b)
  0.000003 seconds (4 allocations: 160 bytes)
"A"


julia> @time collect(b)[1]
  0.000005 seconds (5 allocations: 240 bytes)
"A"


julia> @time first(next(b,start(b)))
  0.000007 seconds (5 allocations: 192 bytes)
"A"
```

Comment: Thanks @Oxinabox , did not remember this variant of `first`. The 4 allocation of `first(b)` are actually an artifact of measurement, no allocations are made. Looking inside the implementation can even double performance again with the following implementation: `getsingleton(x::Set{String}) = x.dict.count == 1 ? x.dict.keys[findfirst(x.dict.slots,0x1)] : throw(ArgumentError("must be a singleton"))`. And use `@benchmark getsingleton(b)` after loading BenchmarkTools package.

Comment: Yeah, I was going to comment as such, but got distracted. thanks. Feel free to edit.

Answer (score 6):

how about

```
julia> collect(b)[1]
"A"
```

**edit**

as the legendary Dan Getz suggested, consider doing

```
julia> collect(take(b,1))[1]
"A"
```

if memory is an issue

Comment: Aha, collect turns a set into an array, I did not know that. Thanks, that's much better!

Comment: This might can allocate a whole vector for `collect(b)`. `collect(take(b,1))[1]` might be more efficient, and even more low-level: `first(next(b,start(b)))`

Comment: Style trivia: I have seen people prefer the use of `[]` instead of `[1]` when it is expected that there is only one item in a list, as a visual way of indicating this is the case.

Comment: If I'd never seen that before, that would undoubtedly confuse me